# Quartz Countertop, Backsplash caulking

Tags: caulking, countertops, backsplash, quartz

[image: counter-backsplash]

Please see attached picture it appears that there is no caulking between the countertop & backsplash. I just noticed this area, it is right behind my faucet where water could drip down into the back of cabinet & cause mold & water damage.
Also, is this a real Quartz Countertop? The contractor who installed it won't provide any details or paperwork about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This gets clear silicone caulk.  If you are arguing with a countertop guy over paperwork good luck.  But he should have caulked.  But this can be done for $4-5 and 5 mins so it isn't the end of the world.